# how to Bypass the Sampler based on previous response value in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have caught up in a situation, where in i need to verify the response of the Previous Sampler for one of the value and if the Value for that is [], then i need to trigger the below request or else then switch to another Sampler.

```
Flow:
Check Response of Sampler for One of the attribute
IF(attribute value==[])
Execute the Sampler under IF Conditions.
ELSE
New Sampler
```

Sample Response:
{"id":8,"merchant_id":"39","title":"Shirts-XtraLarge","subtitle":null,"price":110,"description":null,"images":"image_thumbs":[[]],"options":[],"options_available":[],"custom_options":[]}

I need to check if the attribute custom_options is empty or not! If Empty do some actions and if not empty do some other action !

Need if condition to simulate this!

Help is useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns your JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def size = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), '$..custom_options')[0].size()
   if (size == 0) {
       vars.put('size', 'empty')
   } else {
       vars.put('size', 'notempty')
   }
   ```
3. Add [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) to your Test Plan and use `${size}` as "Switch Value"
4. Add [Simple Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller) as a child of the Switch Controller and give `empty` name to it. Put request(s) related to empty "custom_options" under that `empty` Simple Controller
5. Add another Simple Controller as a child of the Switch Controller and give `notempty` name to it. Put request(s) related to not empty "custom_options" under that `notempty` Simple Controller.

   [image: JMeter Switch Controller]

More information: [Selection Statements in JMeter Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/selection-statements-in-jmeter-made-easy)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri . But however i am getting value for custom_options as "custom_options":[] . How can we get that empy ? Please suggest

Comment: I have extracted the value from Json response for one of the Key. It has two possible values as either Key=[] or 
Key=[{"combination":[{"code":"size","value":"Small"}]},{"combination":
[{"code":"size","value":"Medium"}]}] . I need to check whether Key is [] or it has some values. Could you please help me what is wrong with below implementation: if ("${Key}"=="[]") {
vars.put('size', 'empty')
} else {
vars.put('size', 'notempty')
} My Switch controller is not navigating to Else Part based on above implementation . Help is useful!

Comment: Just amend the first line of the Groovy script and change `custom_options` to `Key`

Comment: No, I am getting response something like this: {"id":27,"merchant_id":"39","title":"Shorts","subtitle":null,"price":100,"description":null,"images":[],"image_thumbs":[],"options":[{"code":"size","label":"Size","extra_info":"","values":[{"label":"Small","value":"4"},{"label":"Medium","value":"5"}]}],"options_available":[{"combination":[{"code":"size","value":"Small"}]},{"combination":[{"code":"size","value":"Medium"}]}],"custom_options":[]}. I have to look for options_available value every time whther its is [] or it has some values. Based on that i need to use that Switch controller .

Comment: As per above answer, this line becomes invalid def size = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), '$..custom_options')[0].size() , as it is querying for a particular value .

Answer (score 2):

A nice to have feature in JMeter would be Else statement, but until then you will have to use 2 [If Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller)

> If Controller allows the user to control whether the test elements below it (its children) are run or not.

Assuming you hold your attribute value using regex/json/css/other post processor extractor add two condition, first is positive and under it the Sampler:

```
${__groovy("${attributeValue}" == "[]")}
```

Second is negative and under it add the New Sampler

```
${__groovy("${attributeValue}" != "[]")}
```

[__groovy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) is encourage to use over default Javascript

> Checking this and using __jexl3 or __groovy function in Condition is advised for performances

Comment: Updated my query.

Comment: if it's regex it should work, anyway you can put default value `[]` and it should work also. if not please specify how you defined the extractor