# how to check null /empty or value based on response from previous Sampler in Jmeter?

Tags: json, jmeter

I have extracted the value from Json response for one of the Key. It has two possible values as either

```
Key=[] or 
Key=[{"combination":[{"code":"size","value":"Small"}]},{"combination":
[{"code":"size","value":"Medium"}]}]
```

I need to check whether Key is [] or it has some values. Could you please help me what is wrong with below implementation:

```
if ("${Key}"=="[]") {
vars.put('size', 'empty')
} else {
vars.put('size', 'notempty')
}
```

My Switch controller is not navigating to Else Part based on above implementation . Help is useful!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to Bypass the Sampler based on previous response value in jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49407770/how-to-bypass-the-sampler-based-on-previous-response-value-in-jmeter)

Comment: which language did you use for your code? JS or Java-based? On Java-based, string comparison is not done that way, it should be via `equals`

Comment: also instead of `"${Key}"` it's more common to do `vars.get("Key")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't ever inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into script body as they may resolve into something which will cause compilation failure or unexpected behaviour. Either use "Parameters" section like:

   [image: JMeter Groovy Parameters]

or use `vars.get('Key')` statement instead.

2. Don't compare string literals using `==`, go for [.equals()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.util.List)) method instead

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on using Groovy scripting in JMeter tests

Answer (score 1):

If you have an already extracted value `Key` and you are using an if controller with the default `JavaScript` you can do the following in the `condition` field:

```
"${Key}".length > 0
```

The `"${Key}"` is evaluating to your `JavaScript` object which is an array. You can check the length of the array to see if there are objects in it.